# Async methods doesn't seem to work on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-phone-8.1

I have the following piece of code (WPF, Windows Phone 8.1):

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var httpResult = client.GetAsync(feed.Url, ct);
string feedData = await httpResult.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

var sf = new SyndicationFeed();
sf.Load(feedData);
```

I'm trying to debug this code. However, after the line:

```
string feedData = await httpResult.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

debugger seems to let application run on its own and never reaches the next line. Why is that? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It's asynchronous, it will reach it when the information is there.

Comment: @CodingChief I can't imagine downloading short XML file via Wifi taking more than 1 minute.

Comment: as John said you were probably in a deadlock that's why it was taking so much time.

Comment: Please note that Windows Phone is not the same as WPF; please consider removing the tag and the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on if you are calling result or wait on the task somewhere upstream, this can result in a deadlock as noted in Stephen Cleary's [blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Mitigate this by awaiting the `client.GetAsync()` and use `ConfigureAwait` where possible to minimize chances of deadlocks:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var httpResult = await client.GetAsync(feed.Url, ct).ConfigureAwait(false);
string feedData = await httpResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

var sf = new SyndicationFeed();
sf.Load(feedData)
```

Comment: Also, change any upstream `Wait` or `Result` calls to use `await` instead.

Comment: @StephenCleary Actually this was the core problem - I waited for the method I posted above via Wait. But this bothers me a little - is there a (working) way to force do some async task synchronously?

Comment: The work is being done asynchronously.  The `ConfigureAwait(false)` indicates that when the work is done you don't care what thread is used to resume the rest of the work.

Comment: @Spook: [No](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27869403/calling-a-3rd-party-async-task-method-synchronously/27871579#27871579).

Comment: @StephenCleary Ok, I expressed myself wrong. By "forcing to run synchronously" I meant waiting for a Task to complete before succeeding further. This should be done by Wait, but it causes deadlocks. So is there another, proper way to do that?

Comment: @Spook: Yes, just use `await task;` instead of `task.Wait();`.

Comment: @StephenCleary And if I don't want the calling method to be *async*?

Comment: @Spook: It's doing asynchronous work, so it should be `async`. `async` does "grow" through the code base naturally, and this should be embraced.