# Calling a 3rd party async Task method synchronously

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm reading hundreds of answers about `await`/`async`, but there is still no answer to this simple question.
There is an awaitable method, written by someone else and it is necessary to wait till it finishes.

```
// cannot be changed
public async Task ThirdPartyAsync(...)
{
    // calls other awaitable methods
    // takes few seconds
}

// I'd like something like this
public void MyPatientCallingMethod(...)
{
    // 1. call the method
    ThirdPartyAsync(...);

    // 2. wait for ThirdPartyAsync to finish (I don't care how long) 

    // 3. return after
    return;
}
```

Yes, I know, it will block the main thread, the UI thread, any other thread... 
It has to be solved this way for safety reasons.

The problem is the return value of the `async` method is `Task`, and there is no `.Result` tag to wait for.
Is there any other deadlock-free solution?

Comment: have you used any synchronization objects or using a lock?

Comment: Why don't you use await? This seems to be intentional.

Comment: Synchronously waiting for the task, as you mentioned, is just going to result in a deadlock.  You need to not synchronously wait in order to not deadlock.

Comment: I didn't use locks. Not clear how it affects the execution order in this case.

Comment: I can't use await because I have to be sure the method is finished before I do anything else.

Comment: @JanosAdorjan That's what await does.. in an async method

Comment: @JanosAdorjan It sounds like you should simply be synchronizing access to some shared resource then, to prevent code that shouldn't be running in parallel to this operation from running.  Blocking the UI thread is a pretty bad way of doing that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Task.Wait()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.wait%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to block on the task.

```
// call the method and wait for ThirdPartyAsync to finish (I don't care how long) 
ThirdPartyAsync(...).Wait();
```

Comment: Thanks! I was afraid this is the same .Wait() method others use to create deadlocks. :)

Comment: @JanosAdorjan It is the same - if you're doing something that could be problematic, it can cause a deadlock.

Answer (score 3):

That's because the best answer is "don't". You should really strive to be async all the way.

> I can't use await because I have to be sure the method is finished before I do anything else.

Note that `async` is serial (meaning the method won't continue past the `await` until the inner method completes); it's just asynchronously serial instead of synchronously serial. So the same programming constructs and logic apply just the same:

```
public async Task MyPatientCallingMethodAsync(...)
{
  // 1. call the method
  var task = ThirdPartyAsync(...);

  // 2. wait for ThirdPartyAsync to finish
  await task;

  // 3. return after
  return;
}
```

This is exactly the approach you should take the vast, *vast* majority of the time.

However, if you positively, absolutely *cannot* do this, then your options are limited. [Stephen Toub describes your options on his blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx).

It is important to note that **none of the options work in all scenarios** and that **every option has drawbacks and pitfalls**. So none of us can say which one is best, or even which one would *work* since we don't know in what context your code is executing.

In summary, your options are:

- Synchronously block using `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` or `Wait` (see @l3arnon's answer for the difference). E.g. `ThirdPartyAsync(...).GetAwaiter().GetResult();`. The drawback to this approach is that deadlocks are a real possibility if called in a UI or ASP.NET context.
- Offload to a thread pool thread and block on that. E.g., `Task.Run(() => ThirdPartyAsync(...)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();`. The drawback to this approach is that the third-party code *must* run on an alternate thread, so this won't work for code assuming a UI or ASP.NET context.
- Execute a nested message loop. E.g., `AsyncContext.Run(() => ThirdPartyAsync(...));`. The drawbacks to this approach are that the nested loop may not do everything you need (i.e., it may not pump Win32 messages, which the third-party code may require), the nested context does not match expected contexts (i.e., this can cause ASP.NET calls to fail), and the nested loop may do too much (i.e., it may pump Win32 messages, which can cause unexpected reentrancy).

In short, although it sounds simple enough, "sync over async" is one of the most complicated things you can (try to) do. And this is the long explanation behind the common answer of "just use async all the way!" :)

Answer (score 2):

Any `Task` without a generic parameter lacks [`Result`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) because it is effectively a `void` return - there *is* no `Result` to wait for.

Instead, what you're looking for is `Task.Wait()` (as mentioned in other answers).

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

1. `Wait()` - Would throw `AggregateException` if the task is faulted.
2. `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` - Would throw the first exception (as `await` would do).
3. [Stephen Cleary's `AsyncContext`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncContext):

```
public void MyPatientCallingMethod(...)
{
    AsyncContext.Run(() => ThirdPartyAsync(...));
}
```

> The `AsyncContext` type provides a context for executing asynchronous operations. The `await` keyword requires a context to return back to; for most programs, this is a UI context, and you don't have to worry about it. ASP.NET also provides a proper context and you don't have to use your own.
>   However, Console applications and Win32 services do not have a suitable context, and `AsyncContext` could be used in those situations.

Answer (score 2):

From the comments it is now apparent what the misunderstanding is: You assume that `await` starts a new thread and continues execution. The opposite is the case: `await` pauses execution until its argument is finished. The `Task`-returning method you are calling is supposed to initiate asynchrony. `await` consumes that.

Use `await`. It's now the standard way to perform long-running work without blocking the UI.